# Routing error for rails - uninitialized constant SubscribersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a `Subscriber` model that takes in a "phone_number" and a "visit" integer. I have two controllers `Subscribers` and `Visits`(super and sub) I have never worked with nested controllers before and I'm having some issues with namespace I believe. Because I getting back the uninitialized constant error. Basically the subscriber controller signs up a subscriber and the visit controller counts the amount of times they've visited by user input of their phone_number. Why am I getting this error? I'll show my code for clarity.

CONTROLLERS

```
  class Subscribers::VisitsController < ApplicationController
   def new
    @subscriber = Subscriber.new
   end

   def create
    @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by_phone_number(params[:phone_number])
    if @subscriber
     @subscriber.visit += 1
     @subscriber.save
     redirect_to subscribers_visits_new_path(:subscriber)
    else
    render "new"
    end
   end
 end


   class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @subscriber = Subscriber.all
 end

 def new
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
 end

 def create
  @subscriber = Subscriber.create(subscriber_params)
  if @subscriber.save
    flash[:success] = "Subscriber Has Been successfully Created"
    redirect_to new_subscriber_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "new"
  end
 end
```

ROUTES

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  resources :subscribers, except: :show
  get '/subscribers/visits/new', to: 'subscribers/visits#new'


  root "welcomes#index"
```

VIEWS

```
  <h1>hey</hey>

  <%= form_for @subscriber do |form| %>
   <div class="form-group">
   <p>
   <%= form.label :phone_number %>
   <%= form.text_field :phone_number %>
   </p>
  <% end %>
```

ERROR

[image]

Comment: can you paste `routes.rb` for these two controllers?

Comment: Got those routes up for you

Comment: What is the purpose of the Visits controller? Can't you just have a visit action within the Subscribers controller, then have a route to `subscribers#visit` and update the visit field there?

Comment: Please provide full logs, including backtrace for the error.  You can find this in the Rails console or in `log/development.log` for the action that's failing.  Copying everything from the `Started` line for the action to the `Completed` line (or to the end of the log) is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably do not need to inherit one controller from another.  Simply define the controllers as you normally would:

**app/controllers/subscribers_controller.rb**

```
class SubscribersController < ApplicationController
  # methods for Subscribers
end
```

**in app/controllers/visits_controller.rb**

```
class VisitsController < ApplicationController
  # methods for Visits
end
```

Note that these *must* to be located in separate files, so that Rails can find the correct source file by the name of the object that it's looking for.  This is a Rails naming convention.

Regarding your routes, you'll need to change to use one of 4 route formats.  Reading the section on [Adding More RESTful Actions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions) in the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide might help.

**1)** To route `visits` as a nested resource, which is what it appears you're actually trying to do, you would use this:

```
resources :subscribers, except: :show do
  resources :visits
end
```

This will produce these routes:

```
GET    /subscribers/new
POST   /subscribers
GET    /subscribers
GET    /subscribers/:id/edit
PATCH  /subscribers/:id/update
DELETE /subscribers/:id/destroy
GET    /subscribers/:id/visits/new
POST   /subscribers/:id/visits
GET    /subscribers/:id/visits
GET    /subscribers/:id/visits/:id
GET    /subscribers/:id/visits/:id/edit
PATCH  /subscribers/:id/visits/:id/update
DELETE /subscribers/:id/visits/:id/destroy
```

This is the typical route structure for nested resources and separate controllers.

**2)** To make `visits#new` a simple collection (non-member) action in the VisitsController, then you likely want this:

```
resources :subscribers, except: :show do
  collection do
    get 'visits/new', to 'visits#new'
    post 'visits', to 'visits#create'
  end
end
```

This will produce these routes:

```
GET    /subscribers/new
POST   /subscribers
GET    /subscribers
GET    /subscribers/:id/edit
PATCH  /subscribers/:id/update
DELETE /subscribers/:id/destroy
GET    /subscribers/visits/new
POST   /subscribers/visits
```

This is typically used to add new top-level routes in an existing resource and controller.

**3)** To construct `visits` as member actions, use this:

```
resources :subscribers, except: :show do
  member do
    get 'visits/new', to 'visits#new'
    post 'visits', to 'visits#create'
  end
end
```

This will produce these routes:

```
GET    /subscribers/new
POST   /subscribers
GET    /subscribers
GET    /subscribers/:id/edit
PATCH  /subscribers/:id/update
DELETE /subscribers/:id/destroy
GET    /subscribers/:id/visits/new
POST   /subscribers/:id/visits
```

This is normally used to add new member routes in an existing resource and controller.

**4)** To simply make `visits` routes appear to be included in `subscribers`, you could use this:

```
get '/subscribers/visits/new', to: 'visits#new'
post '/subscribers/visits', to: 'visits#create'
resources :subscribers, except: :show
```

This will produce these routes:

```
GET    /subscribers/visits/new
POST   /subscribers/visits
GET    /subscribers/new
POST   /subscribers
GET    /subscribers
GET    /subscribers/:id/edit
PATCH  /subscribers/:id/update
DELETE /subscribers/:id/destroy
```

This may be used to make arbitrary routes appear to be included in an existing resource, when they really may be independent.

Comment: Still getting the error. Thanks for your help though

Comment: @CameronBass I updated the answer, and added some options and descriptions for different routes that you might use.  In re-reading your question, it became clear that what you really meant was that you wanted nested *routes*, not nested *controllers*, so this answer includes how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, my guess is you are trying to route url `subscriber/visits/new` to `new` action in `VisitsController`?How about changing this line:

```
get '/subscribers/visits/new', to: 'subscribers/visits#new'
```

to:

```
namespace :subscribers do
  get '/visits/new', to: 'visits#new'
end
```

Also try to move this block above `resources :subscribers, except: :show` if you still get the error.

Cheers